# I have a collection, want to generate a javascript object with it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a collection:

```
@products = Product.where("product_type = ?", 3)
```

I now want to create a javascript object so I can perform lookups in the UI like:

```
my_products[2342]
```

and it will return:

```
"some_name"
```

I believe it should look like:

```
var my_products = {
     2342: "some_name",
     5321: "there blah"

}
```

What's a nice way to generate this in my controller's action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord and Ruby in general has a method `to_json` that should help you do what you're looking for.

Basically construct the array you want to create in Ruby and call `to_json` to create a string that is a valid javascript object to use.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using to_json, but if you want another option you could generate the js object literal notation using an js.erb template.

**views/products/products.js.erb**

```
var products = {
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= "#{product.id}: \"#{@product.name}\"," %>
<% end %> 
}
```

Then, setup a controller method using either a dedicated method or a responds_to block.  Finally, have the AJAX call the method and execute the returned code which will result in you having access to the product variable defined in the js.erb template.

Comment: Be careful with this! You'd need to make sure you encode the value string properly (escape quotes), and if anything but an integer makes it into the name field, you'd need to put the name field in quotes and escape that properly as well.

Comment: @Brandon Very good point.  I was trying to keep my example simple so someone could see the mechanics without getting lost in the implementation details.  You always have to be careful when going about things manually.  Like I said at the start, I recommend using using to_json... but I should probably edit my post to make that a little more clear...

Comment: Fair enough - wasn't implying that you were wrong, was just trying to add to your answer and make the interwebs better!

Comment: @Brandon No worries :-)  I know you weren't implying I was wrong.  I should have mentioned the gotchas.  Good catch on your part :-)